# Toggle back and forth on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a function that changes the text from `+ Expand` to `- Close` on click and back when you click it again. This is really just a basic solution though. I would really like to be able to add CSS to the `+` and `-` without editing everything that's in my `.html()`. I tried adding a span but it didn't seem to work. How might I go about doing that?

JavaScript

```
$('.displaybutton').click(function(){
    $('#otherResponseList').toggle(); 
        if($(this).html() == '- Close'){
            $(this).html('+ Expand');
        } else {
            $(this).html('- Close');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want the `::after` pseudo-selector with the `content` property. As for the javascript, if you're able to use jQuery, the `toggleClass` function is a one-liner:

```js
$('.toggle').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('isOpen')
});
```

```css
.toggle{
  border:1px solid black;
  cursor:pointer;
  padding: 5px;
}
.toggle::after {
  content:"+ expand";
}
.toggle.isOpen::after {
  content:"- close";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="toggle"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can separate the `+` and `-` from the content and keep everything in CSS by using pseudo selectors. Just toggle a class in JS that you can target with CSS.

```js
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click',function() {
  document.getElementById('div').classList.toggle('close');
})
```

```css
.expand:before {
  content: '+';
  color: green;
}
.expand:after {
  content: 'expand';
}
.close:before {
  color: red;
  content: '-';
}
.close:after {
  content: 'close';
}
```

```html
<div id="div" class="expand"></div>
<button id="button">click</button>
```